# Parsing outlook for emails with key-phrase, want to export key-phrase (and it's value) to csv

Tags: powershell, outlook

I get a bunch of automated alerts for users. I mean...a BUNCH. About 800 a day.

I want to document the affected users, and I think a solid way to do it is to parse the folder the emails go into, look for the emails, and export out the line in the email that contains the username.

Example from email:

> Account That Was Locked Out:
>
> Security ID:        S-x-x-xx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxx
>
> Account Name:       jdoe

I want to parse on the third line and just dump out the third line. I've got the regex for the third line in the script I have so far.

```
Add-Type -Assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$inbox = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox)
$RE = [RegEx]'(?sm)Account Name\s*:\s*(?<AccName>.*?)$.*'

$Data = ForEach ($item in $inbox.items){
    if ($item.to -like "<email_that_the_alerts_come_from"){
        if ($item.body -match $RE){
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                AccName   = $Matches.AccName
            }
        }
    }
}
$Data 
$Data | Export-CSv '.\data.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

I'm expecting a csv containing the line I want in each row.

Right now, I run it without error, but the results are empty.

Once I get this working, I'll refine the script to add each user to an array and then count the occurrence of each user.

Comment: The RE should work, did you check if anything passes the 1st if?

Comment: Um, if you're checking `"<email_that_the_alerts_come_from>"`, shouldn't you be looking at `$item.from` instead of `$item.to` in your `-like` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a big dummy.

$item.to should be $item.from.

It was scanning items TO an address, not from.

Whoopsies.

Made the change and ran it, works no prob. Now I just gotta add an array to count the usernames

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is split the body out by each newline and run the regex against each line. If it matches split that line out by : and write that value to the array.

```
$split_body = $item.body.split("`n")

foreach ($line in $split_body)
{
    if ($line -match $RE){
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            AccName = $line.split(":")[1].trim()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try having it output to the host instead of writing it to a variable and see if it outputs anything. Or use a debugger and set a breakpoint on each line to see if it is successfully splitting the body up, what each line is, etc.